# How to align Dates from different columns in R or Excel

Tags: r, excel, date

I have a dataset of variables with each variable having a different date span. They are presented as in the following example (taken the first two cases out of 500):

```
DatesV1     DatesV2
29/12/1995  19/07/2001
02/01/1996  20/07/2001
03/01/1996  23/07/2001
04/01/1996  24/07/2001
05/01/1996  25/07/2001
08/01/1996  26/07/2001
09/01/1996  27/07/2001
10/01/1996  30/07/2001
11/01/1996  31/07/2001
12/01/1996  01/08/2001
15/01/1996  02/08/2001
16/01/1996  03/08/2001
17/01/1996  06/08/2001
```

What I want to happen is for the dates in `DatesV2` to align with the dates in `DatesV1`. This means that `DatesV2` will start with a few `NA` until the row that the dates align. Like this:

```
DatesV1     DatesV2
 ...         ...
17/07/2001  NA
18/07/2001  NA
19/07/2001  19/07/2001
20/07/2001  20/07/2001
 ...         ...
```

In the Example Set, I have the example of exactly what I am trying to do. I can't find of a fast computational way to do it in either R or Excel for the 500 variables that I have.
[Example Set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikody7jglj8rxpg/Example.xlsx?dl=0)
I have tried something like this:

```
nhat<-which(Example$DatesV2[1]==Example$DatesV1)
nend<-which(Example$DatesV1[length(Example$DatesV1)-1]==Example$DatesV2)
Example$Apotelesma<- c(rep(NA,nhat-1),Example$DatesV2[1:nend],NA)
```

Which is an initial test that works for two dates. Only thing is that dates appear as numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution using some re-shaping. I'm using a simple example:

```
df = data.frame(DatesV1 = c("24/07/2001","25/07/2001","26/07/2001"),
                DatesV2 = c("25/07/2001","26/07/2001","27/07/2001"),
                DatesV3 = c("26/07/2001","27/07/2001","28/07/2001"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# update to date columns (only if needed)
df = df %>% mutate_all(dmy)

df %>%
  gather() %>%             # reshape dataset
  mutate(id = value) %>%   # use date values as row ids
  spread(key, value) %>%   # reshape again
  select(-id)              # remove ids

#      DatesV1    DatesV2    DatesV3
# 1 2001-07-24       <NA>       <NA>
# 2 2001-07-25 2001-07-25       <NA>
# 3 2001-07-26 2001-07-26 2001-07-26
# 4       <NA> 2001-07-27 2001-07-27
# 5       <NA>       <NA> 2001-07-28
```

Comment: I get this: `df = df %>% mutate_all(dmy)
Warning messages:
1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. `

Also:
`class(df$DatesV1)
[1] "Date"`

Comment: `dmy(df$DatesV2)` returns `NA` for all entries.

Comment: I assume you managed to run my example, but you get this for your full dataset, right? Either you have other variables that are not dates, or you have another date format.

Comment: Yes! Your example runs perfectly! Just when I expand it my case the errors appear.

Comment: Maybe you don't need that piece of code if your columns are `date` already. Do they have the same format? `dmy` is "day-month-year".

Comment: Yes, all dates are in the "d-m-Y" format!  But even when i do not run the `dmy` part, then this I get: `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (8899, 8900, 8901,...`

Comment: Hmmm. Any chance you have duplicate rows in your original dataset? You'll have to exclude them in the beginning.

Comment: I think it's the NAs. If you see the Example Set I have uploaded there are NAs in the dataset. I should have figured that out sooner that they cause that error.

Comment: I thought you didn't have NAs in your original dataset. I thought they appear when you try to align the dates in the two columns

Comment: Those are the problematic parts of the data :/ that make this task almost impossible!

Comment: Can you check if `gather() %>% na.omit() %>% ...` works? This filters out any NAs.

Comment: the thing is I do not want the NAs to go away. They have to stay in. I know it sounds weird.

Answer (score 0):

This an ugly/messy method if you like, but it gets the job done. Any faster and tidier way would be better.

```
n<-nrow(DataAlignment)
Newdata<-matrix(0,5148,ncol(DataAlignment))
loops<-ncol(DataAlignment)-1
for(i in 1:loops){
  nhat<-which(DataAlignment[1,i+1]==DataAlignment[,1]) #finds the position of the first date in column 2 according to the first column
  nend<-which(DataAlignment[n,1]==DataAlignment[,i+1]) #finds the position of last date in col 2 according to the first column

  if(nhat==1 | nend != 5148){ #takes into account when they start at the same time but end in different dates
  Newdata[,i+1]<-c(DataAlignment[c(1:nend),i+1],rep(NA,n-nend))  
  }
  else{if(nhat==1| nend==5148){Newdata[,i+1]<-c(DataAlignment[,i+1])} #this takes account when they start and end at the same time
  else{if(nhat!=1){
  Newdata[,i+1]<-c(rep(NA,nhat-1),DataAlignment[c(1:nend),i+1])}}} #creates the new data
}
```